# How to convert useLazyAsyncData() result data string to json object?

Tags: nuxtjs3

How to get `report` converted from string to json object in such configuration?

```
const { pending, data: report } = useLazyAsyncData("report", () =>
  $fetch("https://my-api.com/my-report")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If raw string comes from your API, you may use `JSON.parse(report)` to de-serialize it (providing it contains valid object definition)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: I'm currently using JSON.parse() in my template, is there a way to convert it on the fly so that report is a json?

Comment: I never actually tried that yet, but you can pass 3rd argument to useLazyAsyncData, which is an options object ([see here](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-async-data)). And inside this object, you can use `transform` to supply a function, that do something with the incomming data. So I assume, you should have something like `{ transform(data) { return JSON.parse(data); } }` and it should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
const { pending, data: report } = useLazyAsyncData("report", () => {
  return $fetch("https://my-api.com/my-report")
}, { transform: (input) => JSON.parse(input) });
```